# What does the Rig Veda say about the forests and healing properties of plants and animals

Tags: rig-veda, animals, plants

This article mentions [the forests, and healing properties of plants and animals](https://www.academia.edu/16028337/VEDIC_SCIENCE_AND_ENVIRONMENT)

> ...Similarly the Rig-Veda mentions about the forest goddess and healing
>   properties of plants, tribes of fishes, goats, and etc.

What does the Rig Veda say about the forests and healing properties of plants and animals?

Answer (score 6):

[Here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10097.htm) Rig Veda mention the qualities of herbs and plants:

> या ओषधीः पूर्वा जाता देवेभ्यस्त्रियुगं पुरा | 
>       मनैनु बभ्रूणामहं शतं धामानि सप्त च || 
>       शतं वो अम्ब धामानि सहस्रमुत वो रुहः | 
>       अधाशतक्रत्वो यूयमिमं मे अगदं कर्त || 
>       ओषधीः परति मोदध्वं पुष्पवतीः परसूवरीः | 
>       अश्वािव सजित्वरीर्वीरुधः पारयिष्ण्वः || 
>       ओषधीरिति मातरस्तद वो देवीरुप बरुवे | 
>       सनेयमश्वंगां वास आत्मानं तव पूरुष || 
>       अश्वत्थे वो निषदनं पर्णे वो वसतिष कर्ता | 
>       गोभाज इत्किलासथ यत सनवथ पूरुषम || 
>       यत्रौषधीः समग्मत राजानः समिताविव | 
>       विप्रः सौच्यते भिषग रक्षोहामीवचातनः || 
>       अश्वावतीं सोमावतीमूर्जयन्तीमुदोजसम | 
>       आवित्सिसर्वा ओषधीरस्मा अरिष्टतातये || 
>       उच्छुष्मा ओषधीनां गावो गोष्ठादिवेरते | 
>       धनंसनिष्यन्तीनामात्मानं तव पूरुष || 
>       इष्क्र्तिर्नाम वो माताथो यूयं सथ निष्क्र्तीः | 
>       सीराःपतत्र्णी सथन यदामयति निष कर्थ || 
>       अति विश्वाः परिष्ठा सतेन इव वरजमक्रमुः | 
>       ओषधीःप्राचुच्यवुर्यत किं च तन्वो रपः || 
>       यदिमा वाजयन्नहमोषधीर्हस्त आदधे | 
>       आत्मायक्ष्मस्य नश्यति पुरा जीवग्र्भो यथा || 
>       यस्यौषधीः परसर्पथाङगम-अञ्गं परुष-परुः | 
>       ततोयक्ष्मं वि बाधध्व उग्रो मध्यमशीरिव || 
>       साकं यक्ष्म पर पत चाषेण किकिदीविना | 
>       साकंवातस्य धराज्या साकं नश्य निहाकया || 
>       अन्या वो अन्यामवत्वन्यान्यस्या उपावत | 
>       ताः सर्वाःसंविदाना इदं मे परावता वचः || 
>       याः फलिनीर्या अफला अपुष्पा याश्च पुष्पिणीः | 
>       बर्हस्पतिप्रसूतास्ता नो मुञ्चन्त्वंहसः || 
>       मुञ्चन्तु मा शपथ्यादथो वरुण्यादुत | 
>       अथो यमस्यपड्बीशात सर्वस्माद देवकिल्बिषात || 
>       अवपतन्तीरवदन दिव ओषधयस परि | 
>       यं जीवमश्नवामहै न स रिष्याति पूरुषः || 
>       या ओषधीः सोमराज्ञीर्बह्वीः शतविचक्षणाः | 
>       तासां तवमस्युत्तमारं कामाय शं हर्दे || 
>       ओषधीः सोमराज्ञीर्विष्ठिताः पर्थिवीमनु | 
>       बर्हस्पतिप्रसूता अस्यै सं दत्त वीर्यम || 
>       मा वो रिषत खनिता यस्मै चाहं खनामि वः | 
>       दविपच्चतुष्पदस्माकं सर्वमस्त्वनातुरम || 
>       याश्चेदमुपश्र्ण्वन्ति याश्च दूरं परागताः | 
>       सर्वाः संगत्य वीरुधो.अस्यै सं दत्त वीर्यम || 
>       ओषधयः सं वदन्ते सोमेन सह राज्ञा | 
>       यस्मै कर्णोतिब्राह्मणस्तं राजन पारयामसि || 
>       तवमुत्तमास्योषधे तव वर्क्षा उपस्तयः | 
>       उपस्तिरस्तुसो.अस्माकं यो अस्मानभिदासति ||

[Here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10097.htm) is its translation:

> 1. HERBS that sprang up in time of
>      old, there ages earlier than the Gods,—
>      Of these, whose hue is brown, will I declare the hundred powers and seven.
> 2. Ye, Mothers, have a hundred homes, yea, and a thousand thousanr growths.
>      Do ye who have a thousand powers free this my patient from disease.
> 3. Be glad and joyful in the Plants, both blossoming and bearing fruit,
>      Plants that will lead us to success like mares who conquer in the race.
> 4. Plants, by this name I speak to you, Mothers, to you
>      the Goddesses:Steed, cow, and garment may I win, 
>      win back thy very self, O man.
> 5. The Holy Fig tree is your home, your mansion is the Parna tree:
>      Winners of cattle shali ye be if ye regain for me this man.
> 6. He who hath store of Herbs at hand like Kings amid a crowd of men,—
>      Physician is that sage's name, fiend-slayer, chaser of disease.
> 7. Herbs rich in Soma, rich in steeds, in nourishments, in strengthening power,—
>      All these have I provided here, that this man may be whole again.
> 8. The healing virtues of the Plants stream forth like cattle from the stall,—
>      Plants that shall win me store of wealth, and save thy vital breath, O man.
> 9. Reliever is your mother's name, and hence Restorers are ye called.
>      Rivers are ye with wings that fly: keep far whatever brings disease.
> 10. Over all fences have they passed, as steals a thief into the fold.
>       The Plants have driven from the frame whatever malady was there.
> 11. When, bringing back the vanished strength, I hold these herbs within my hand, The spirit of disease departs ere he can seize upon
>       the life.
> 12. He through whose frame, O Plants, ye creep member by member, joint by joint,—
>       From him ye drive away disease like some strong arbiter of strife.
> 13. Fly, Spirit of Disease, begone, with the blue jay and kingfisher.
>       Fly with the wind's impetuousspeed, vanish together with the storm.
> 14. Help every one the other, lend assistance each of you to each,
>       All of you be accordant, give furtherance to this speech of mine.
> 15. Let fruitful Plants, and fruitless, those that blossom, and the blossomless,
>       Urged onward by Bṛhaspati, release us from our pain and grief;
> 16. Release me from the curse's plague and woe that comes from Varuṇa;
>       Free me from Yama's fetter, from sin and offence against the Gods.
> 17. What time, descending from the sky, the Plants flew earthward, thus they spake:
>       No evil shall befall the man whom while he liveth we pervade,
> 18. Of all the many Plants whose King is, Soma, Plants of hundred forms,
>       Thou art the Plant most excellent, prompt to the wish, sweet to the heart.
> 19. O all ye various Herbs whose King is Soma, that o’erspread the earth,
>       Urged onward by Bṛhaspati, combine your virtue in this Plant.
> 20. Unharmed be he who digs you up, unharmed the man for whom I dig:
>       And let no malady attack biped or quadruped of ours.
> 21. All Plants that hear this speech, and those that have departed far away,
>       Come all assembled and confer your healing power upon this Herb.
> 22. With Soma as their Sovran Lord the Plants hold colloquy and say:
>       O King, we save from death the man whose cure a Brahman undertakes.
> 23. Most excellent of all art thou, O Plant thy vassals are the trees.
>       Let him be subject to our power, the man who seeks to injure us.

And [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv10146.htm) it mentions about Aranyani or Forest Goddess:

> अरण्यान्यरण्यान्यसौ या परेव नश्यसि | 
>  कथाग्रामं न पर्छसि न तवा
>   भीरिव विन्दती.अ.अ.अन || 
>  वर्षारवाय वदते यदुपावति चिच्चिकः | 
>   आघाटिभिरिवधावयन्नरण्यानिर्महीयते || 
>  उत गाव इवादन्त्युत वेश्मेव
>   दर्श्यते | 
>  उतो अरण्यानिःसायं शकटीरिव सर्जति || 
>  गामङगैष आ
>   हवयति दार्वङगैषो अपावधीत | 
>  वसन्नरण्यान्यां सायमक्रुक्षदिति मन्यते
>   || 
>  न वा अरण्यानिर्हन्त्यन्यश्चेन नाभिगछति | 
>  सवादोःफलस्य
>   जग्ध्वाय यथाकामं नि पद्यते || 
>  आञ्जनगन्धिं सुरभिं
>   बह्वन्नामक्र्षीवलाम | 
>  पराहम्म्र्गाणां मातरमरण्यानिमशंसिषम ||

And [here](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10146.htm) is its translation

> 1. GODDESS of wild and forest who seemest to vanish from the sight. How is it that thou seekest not the village? Art thou not afraid?
> 2. What time the grasshopper replies and swells the shrill cicala's voice, Seeming to sound with tinkling bells, the Lady of the Wood
>      exults.
> 3. And, yonder, cattle seem to graze, what seems a dwelling-place appears: Or else at eve the Lady of the Forest seems to free the
>      wains.
> 4. Here one is calling to his cow, another there hath felled a tree: At eve the dweller in the wood fancies that somebody hath screamed.
> 5. The Goddess never slays, unless some murderous enemy approach. Man eats of savoury fruit and then takes, even as he wills, his rest.
> 6. Now have I praised the Forest Queen, sweet-scented, redolent of balm, The Mother of all sylvan things, who tills not but hath stores
>      of food

.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Should probably remove the verses, answer is too long...

Comment: @sv. Let Triyugi decide.

Comment: @TheDestroyer and sv. You may edit the answer.